# connect Oracle developer with Access or Microsoft SQL database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, dbase

I was wondering if it's possible to connect Oracle Developer to Microsoft SQL database or Microsoft Access Database. I believe there is a way to do that. If there is, I would rather to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle SQL Developer can connect to MSFT SQL Server. You just need to get the jTDS jdbc driver and add it to SQLDev via the preferences.

For Access, you'll need an older version of SQL Developer - I recommend version 3.1. We removed support for Access because newer versions of Java don't support an ODBC bridge that we were using.

[image]

I talk about how to add the JDBC drivers [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/).